# no data from a query result is echoed - mysqli/php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to output data from a query result into a text input and a normal echo but it is not outputting anything. I have no errors in php, am I doing something wrong in mysqli code that it is not echoing anything?

```
function ShowAssessment()
    {
        $sessiondetailsquery = "
            SELECT SessionId, SessionName        
            FROM Session
            WHERE
            (SessionId = ?)";

        global $mysqli;

        $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessiondetailsquery);


        $sqlstmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["session"]);


        $sessiondetailsqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessiondetailsquery);
        // You only need to call bind_param once
        $sessiondetailsqrystmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["session"]);
        // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
        $sessiondetailsqrystmt->execute(); 
        $sessiondetailsqrystmt->bind_result($detailsSessionId,$detailsSessionName);?>

        $sqlstmt->fetch(); 

        $sqlstmt->close(); 

        <h3>CHOSEN ASSESSMENT</h3>
        <input type='text' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='<?php $detailsSessionId; ?>' /></td> 
        <br>
        <strong>Assessment:</strong> <?php echo $detailsSessionName; ?>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 2 bind_params doing the same thing in your code.